# Xpage authentication

Tags: xpages

I have an application that will have anonymous access on all the xpages except a couple. I need to force the user to login for those xpages. Is using the beforepageload event to check and redirecting the user to logon page the right way or is there a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes this would be a valid way to do it and is how I handle the situation in a couple of my own apps.

This is the code that I use

```
if (context.getUser().getCommonName() == "Anonymous"){
   sessionScope.put("entryPage",context.getUrl().getPath() + context.getUrl().getQueryString())
   context.redirectToPage("/login.xsp");
}
```

I have this setup as a function that I just call from the beforePageLoad event. I'm redirecting to another XPage but you could also redirect to the database.nsf?login which will use the authentication type setup on the server.

Comment: No problem. The sessionScope.entryPage in my code is so I can redirect back to the original page that forced the login.

Answer (score 10):

The best solution would be to add an ACL to the XPages which require the user to login, then you're not reliant on your own code but can let the server do the work for you.

To add an ACL, go to the All Properties of the XPage and look for the Access Control section. Then you can add one or more configurations to define who has what access - e.g. Anonymous has no access, or people in a group or role have access etc.

Matt

Answer (score 4):

I fully support the answer provided by: **Matt White**

> The best solution would be to add an ACL to the XPages

In my XPages App I'm using the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

  <xp:this.acl>
    <xp:acl>
       <xp:this.entries>
          <xp:aclEntry type="ANONYMOUS" right="READER"></xp:aclEntry>
          <xp:aclEntry type="DEFAULT" right="EDITOR"></xp:aclEntry>
       </xp:this.entries>
    </xp:acl>
 </xp:this.acl>

...XPage content here...

</xp:view>
```

It performs just perfect! Try it! )

Answer (score 1):

You can use following samples for solution.

[1- OpenNTF - Xpages Dojo Login Custom Control Project](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=Xpages%20Dojo%20Login%20Custom%20Control)

[2- LotusNotus.Com from Serdar Basegmez - Authenticating Notes users for Web apps automatically...](http://lotusnotus.com/lotusnotus_en.nsf/dx/authenticating-notes-users-for-web-apps-automatically....htm)

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a look here:

http://www.ovalbusinesssolutions.co.uk/thoughts/securing-your-xpages-website-using-public-access-2

If you uncheck the box "Available to Public Access Users" (by default it is unchecked) for the XPages where you want to force a log-in, the user will be automatically routed to the login and after the successful login, back to the XPage he tried to open.